# Groovy: Plucking values out of a Map and into a Set

Tags: groovy, collections

Groovy here. I have a class `Fizz`:

```
@Canonical
class Fizz {
  Integer id
  String name
}
```

In my program, I compose a map of them by their integral `id` field:

```
// Here, each key of the map corresponds to the Fizz#id of its value
// example:
// allFizzes[1] = new Fizz(1, 'Foobar')
// allFizzes[3004] = new Fizz(3004, 'Wakka wakka')
Map<Integer,Fizz> allFizzes = getSomehow()
```

I would know like to obtain a set of "bad" Fizzes whose `name` equals the string 'Sampson'. My best attempt:

```
Set<Fizz> badFizzes = allFizzes.find { k,v -> v.equals('Sampson') }
```

However this gives me runtime errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '24={
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Sampson"
},
  ' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry' to class 'java.util.Set'
```

So it looks like even though I'm specifying `v.equals('Sampson')` that Groovy is strill trying to save a Map key,value pair into a `Set`. What's the *Grooviest* solution here?

Comment: I believe you may want to use `findAll` instead of `find`. `findAll` returns a collection whereas `find` returns a single Object.

Comment: Also, `v.equals('Sampson')` should be `v.name == 'Sampson'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `findAll` (which returns a Collection) in place of `find` (which returns an Object). `findAll` applies the passed in closure to each EntrySet in the Map and returns a new collection with elements that satisfied your closure's criteria. You can then call `values()` on this newly returned collection.

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = ["fizzStrength":29, "fizzQuality": 123, "fizzFizziness":3]
Set<Integer> found = myMap.findAll { k,v -> v > 4 }.values() // returns [29, 123]
```